# Creating custom rails method for finding objects belonging to a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create a method in Rails that will return all objects belonging to a user (a route that calls the method on a given URL scheme). Each object contains a user property, but I have almost 400,000 objects now, so returning them all and sorting in the app is becoming very slow.

I'm at a loss for how to accomplish this. I'd like to be able to call this method remotely using a third party Objective-C class NSRails. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a couple of different ways, either by creating a scope on the object and filtering through a query parameter, or by setting up a non resourceful route dedicated to this action. I will go through an example of the latter.

```
# in config/routes.rb

resources :object do 
  get "users/:user_id", on: :collection
end
```

This will map your route to `objects/users/:user_id`

```
# In your ObjectsController

def users
  @objects = Object.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
end
```

For quicker read speed, add an index to the user_id field of your object since you will be querying the database against that value. Hope this helps out.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll try this in the morning and report back!

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to the developer of NSRails who was incredibly helpful. While @tomciopp had what I'm sure worked, I ended up going with a solution from Dan. Here it is:

```
users_controller.rb
...
  # GET /users/find_by_email
  def find_by_email
    @users = User.where(:email => params[:email])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @users.to_json }
    end
  end
…

routes.rb
…
match 'users/find_by_email' => 'users#find_by_email'
…
```